# Can I create 5 integers if for example int x = 5 in Java

Tags: java

For example, I have a coin with a 1/2 chance to land on heads or tails. I want to flip it a certain amount of times that the user asks for.

```
Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println(How many times do you want to flip the coin?)
int flips = userinput.nextInt();
```

if

```
flips = 5
```

Can I create 5 integers that are equal to either 1 or 2 (Heads or tails)

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, you may want to use a dynamic data structure in order to easily access your variables. E.g.:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
System.out.println(How many times do you want to flip the coin?)
int flips = userinput.nextInt();
ArrayList<String> results;
if (flips == 5) {
    results = new ArrayList(5) // creates a list with 5 positons for Strings
} else {
    results = new ArrayLists(1) // creates a list with 1 position for String
}
results.set(0, "heads"); //sets the first flip to "heads"
System.out.println("The first flip was: " + results.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you're probably looking for is a for-loop.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html